# For Android how would I get data from a date and date range in SQLite where Android variables can be passed to the query?

Tags: android, sqlite, date

For Android how would I get data from a specific date and date range in SQLite where Android variables can be passed to the query?  For example if the user wants to find data in a field of the user's choosing, between two dates of the user's choosing.  A date column has already been populated using the following format:

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method in the database helper something like the following :-

```
public Cursor getDatesInRange(String fromDate, String toDate) {
    String whereclause = COL_DATE + " >= datetime(?) and " + COL_DATE + " <= datetime(?)";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{fromDate,toDate};
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
            TB_DATE,
            null,
            whereclause,
            whereargs,
            null,
            null,
            COL_DATE + " DESC"
    );
}
```

- **COL_DATE** holding the name of the respective column.
- **TB_DATE** holding the name of the respective table.
- **fromDate** and **toDate** need to be in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss or a sub-format noting that HH:mm:ss if not given equates to **00:00:00**.

  - e.g yyyy-MM-dd would suffice in some situations.
- *An assumption has been made regarding the ORDER by using `COL_DATE + " DESC"`*
- For a specific date you just use the same date BUT using hours/mins/secs as from 
  yyyy-MM-dd **00:00:00** and to yyyy-MM-dd- **23:59:59**.

### Example

The Databasehelper :-

public class SO50282282DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DBNAME = "SO50282282";
public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
public static final String TB_DATE = "tbl_date";
public static final String COL_DATE = "date_column";

public SO50282282DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TB_DATE +
            "(" +
            COL_DATE + " TEXT " +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(crtsql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public long addDate(String date) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_DATE,date);
    return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TB_DATE,null,cv);
}

public Cursor getDatesInRange(String fromdate, String toDate) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{"*,rowid AS id"};
    String whereclause = COL_DATE + " >= datetime(?) and " + COL_DATE + " <= datetime(?)";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{fromdate,toDate};
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
            TB_DATE,
            columns,
            whereclause,
            whereargs,
            null,
            null,
            COL_DATE + " DESC"
    );
}
```

}

- Note **rowid** extracted purely for demonstration

In an activity :-

```
    SO50282282DBHelper dbhlpr = new SO50282282DBHelper(this);
    // Only insert some testing rows if there are none
    if (
            DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(
            dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase(),
            SO50282282DBHelper.TB_DATE
            ) < 1) {
        dbhlpr.addDate("2018-01-01 08:30:56");
        dbhlpr.addDate("2018-02-01 09:31:56");
        dbhlpr.addDate("2018-03-01 10:32:56");
        dbhlpr.addDate("2018-04-01 11:35:56");
        dbhlpr.addDate("2018-05-01 12:36:56");
        dbhlpr.addDate("2018-02-02 12:37:56");
        dbhlpr.addDate("2018-03-02 14:38:56");
    }
    // gets rows id=3 id=4 id=7
    //      (id 1, 2 and 6 before 2018-03-01)(id 5 after 2018-04-30)
    Cursor csr = dbhlpr.getDatesInRange("2018-03-01","2018-04-30");
    SO50282282LogDates(csr);
    // gets rows id = 1
    csr = dbhlpr.getDatesInRange("2018-01-01 00:00:00","2018-01-01 23:59:59");
    SO50282282LogDates(csr);
    //gets rows id = 2, 3, 4, 6 and 7
    csr = dbhlpr.getDatesInRange("2018-01-01 08:30:57","2018-05-01 12:36:55");
    SO50282282LogDates(csr);
    csr.close();
```

Results in the Log :-

For the First of the three (using `dbhlpr.getDatesInRange("2018-03-01","2018-04-30")`):-

```
05-11 03:56:44.777 2203-2203/? D/EXTRACTED_DATE: Date is 2018-04-01 11:35:56 from row #  4
    Date is 2018-03-02 14:38:56 from row #  7
    Date is 2018-03-01 10:32:56 from row #  3
```

For the Second (using `getDatesInRange("2018-01-01 00:00:00","2018-01-01 23:59:59")`):-

```
    Date is 2018-01-01 08:30:56 from row #  1
```

And finally (using `getDatesInRange("2018-01-01 08:30:57","2018-05-01 12:36:55")`):-

```
05-11 03:56:44.781 2203-2203/? D/EXTRACTED_DATE: Date is 2018-04-01 11:35:56 from row #  4
    Date is 2018-03-02 14:38:56 from row #  7
    Date is 2018-03-01 10:32:56 from row #  3
    Date is 2018-02-02 12:37:56 from row #  6
    Date is 2018-02-01 09:31:56 from row #  2
```